# check whether the item in spinner selected or not

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am trying to write a simple app for android. I want to display toast message if there is no item is selected in spinner. .I use two progress bar to do this.I have tried the code given below.

```
        String selection =sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
System.out.println("selected item "+selection);
if(selection=="[selection]")
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "gfdgdghfhf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use a string value as flag of selection



String status="not_selected";  

yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                MyData d = items[position];

                status=d.getValue();
            }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      status="not_selected";
        }
    });

if(status.equqls("not_selected"){
            //show toast here 


                    }
```